# MySQL Cluster Node Specific Hardware

Tags: mysql, apache, hardware, mysql-cluster, server-hardware

I am looking at setting up a MySQL Cluster with two high end dell servers (duel opteron 4386 cpus, 16gb ram and RAID 10 SAS). I also have a handful of other high end machines that are i7 with 20gb+ ram each on average.

What is the hardware focus for each node in MySQL Cluster?

I know that the management node requires very little as it is simply an interface to control the cluster and can be put on the same machine as mysqld.

What hardware is the most important for the MySQL node and for the data nodes (hard disk IO, ram, cpu etc?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the management node needs very little resource - just make sure you run it/them on different machines to the data nodes.

Data Nodes like lots of memory as by default all of the data is held in RAM; they can also make good use of fast cores and in more recent releases lots of them (perhaps upto about 48). Multiple spindles for redo/undo logs,checkpoints, disk table files etc. can speed things up.

MySQL Servers don't need a lot of RAM as they don't store the Cluster data and in most cases you wouldn't use the query cache. If replicating to a second Cluster then you should make sure that they have enough disk space for the binary log files.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I opted to get two R515 servers from Dell with 8 cores each as I read somewhere that MySQL Cluster can at most use 8 cores (at least for now). Just need a good tutorial on how to set it all up on windows 2008 server.